# ios:set tabbar top border only

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, border

> i have apply this bellow code for tabbar border

self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.8 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.borderColor =  self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor.cgColor

> but using this code border apply at all side and i want border only top side of tabbar[my tabbar that show tabbar border all side (top,left,right,bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFS2I.png) 
>   [i want tabbar like this sample image that show border only at top side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzntW.png)
>   now what should i have to do ?
>   Thanks

Comment: it is not relevant to my question @Lalitkumar i cant found answer of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//First, remove the default top line and background
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()

//Then, add the custom top line view with custom color. And set the default background color of tabbar     
let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 1))
lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.addSubview(lineView)
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 248.0/255.0, green: 248.0/255.0, blue: 248.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

It looks like this:
[image]